# Core graphics rotate rectangle

Tags: ios, rotation, core-graphics

With this formula I got angle

```
double rotateAngle = atan2(y,x)
```

with this code I can draw a rectangle

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x,y , width ,height);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

How can I rotate the rectangle around the angle ?

Answer (score 29):

Here's how you'd do that:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGFloat halfWidth = width / 2.0;
CGFloat halfHeight = height / 2.0;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(x + halfWidth, y + halfHeight);

// Move to the center of the rectangle:
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, center.x, center.y);
// Rotate:
CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotateAngle);
// Draw the rectangle centered about the center:
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, width, height);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Perfect. A mod should mark this as accepted, seeing as user1125890 apparently have better things to do. I could never have figured this out myself. Thank you!

Comment: You saved my life brother. i tried to rotae my rect as per my superview label size .. just going in darker and datker from last few days. but your solution work like charm. thanks a lot.